# Guest Sign in Google play game service

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

i'm making a multiplayer game and i implemented the Google play game service (realtime multiplayer) and all worked well, but was wondering if is it possible to sign in (log-in) and play as guest without having a google account?

Thanks in advance